# Is it possible to Load Data directly from Multiple Excel Sheets Into Pipe Delimited TXT File using SSIS..?

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, delimited

Can we load the data from a multiple excel sheets into txt file using SSIS without a temp table in between..?

I Tried it by loading the data of the multiple excel sheets into a table. After I loaded the data from the table into a TXT file. Is it possible to do without loading into the table Using SSIS..?

Comment: Have you tried? Try an excel source and a text target

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes. It can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by creating a vatiable :
[image]

Add a Foreach Loop Container in the Control Flow Task :

[image]

With the following configuration :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]